# Javascript onkeydown event on HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeydown, listeners

I am trying to make an application that moves a WebGL (three.js) camera around using WASD. But, when I use

```
onkeydown = function(e) { alert("a") }
```

and try to type in a text box on the same page, it triggers the listener. I changed the code to look like this:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.onkeydown = function(e) { alert("a") }
```

but this didn't work because HTML content hasn't loaded yet, so, I added jQuery:

```
var container;
$(function() {
  container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.onkeydown = function(e) { alert("a") }
});
```

Now, the listener doesn't work at all, so is it possible to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `DOMContentLoaded` event to delay execution until after the HTML has loaded. In plain JavaScript, it will look something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { alert("a") });
});
```

With jQuery, it's pretty much the same, but a little shorter:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    $(container).keydown(function(e) { alert("a") });
});
```

(Plus what Oriol said about `tabindex`.)

Comment: While this does make sense, when I try it does not work. Correct me if I'm wrong, but a listener cannot be triggered if it is not in the global scope.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by not being in the global scope. Maybe there's some important detail about your code that you've left out? Also, be sure the container is focusable like Oriol said.

Comment: I'm sorry if that confused you. What I meant is this:
`function a() { //I cannot expect a listener inside a function to trigger when }`
`//it is triggered outside the function`

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand, but let me try to guess. If you're saying that a listener that you set from within a function cannot be triggered once the function has finished, you'd be wrong. By setting a listener, you're altering global state. It doesn't matter where you do it.

Comment: For some reason when I tried using jQuery listeners it didn't work. However it worked with plain JS.

Comment: Judging by your sample code, you were doing jQuery wrong. You wrote `$(function() {...})`, which doesn't do anything useful. See my post for the proper way. (Or, just do it with plain JS, if you prefer.)

Comment: Well, I have used `$(function() {});` a lot before, and to me it acts as `$(document).ready(function() {});`. It's just shorter.

Comment: Really? Interesting. I've never used that. I don't think I'd recommend it, either. (You also made me notice that my example incorrectly used load rather than ready, so thanks for that.)

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it work, your element must be [focused](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#focus):

> When an element is *focused*, key events received by the document must
>   be targeted at that element. There may be no element focused; when no
>   element is focused, key events received by the document must be
>   targeted at [the body element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-body-element-0)

However, in order to be able to focus the element, it must be [focusable](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#focusable):

> An element is focusable if all of the following conditions are met:
>
> - The element's [tabindex focus flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#specially-focusable) is set.
> - The element is either [being rendered](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#being-rendered) or is a descendant of a [`canvas`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-canvas-element) element that [represents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#represents) [embedded content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedded-content-2).
> - The element is not [inert](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#inert).
> - The element is not [disabled](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html#concept-element-disabled).

Usually, the problem is the lack of the tabindex focus flag. You set add it by adding a [`tabindex` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-tabindex) with an integral value.

Once the element is focusable, you need to focus it. There are multiple ways to do that, e.g.

- With JavaScript, using the [`.focus()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#dom-focus) method.
- Clicking it with the mouse (without cancelling the `mousedown` event)
- Pressing the tab key to navigate through the focusable elements. If you used a non-negative `tabindex`, the element will eventually become focused.

For example:

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.onkeydown = function(e) { alert("Key detected") }
```

```css
#container { border: 3px solid red; padding: 10px; }
#container:focus { border-color: green; }
#container:after { content: "Now I'm not focused, so it won't work. Click me."; }
#container:focus:after { content: "Now I'm focused, so it will work. Press a key."; }
```

```html
<div id="container" tabindex="-1"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Does this work with canvas as well?

Comment: @Firephoenix Yes, it should work with canvas (but not with shapes drawn in a canvas).

Comment: For testing purposes, I tried to focus the element inside the code and then press buttons. However, it did not detect a keydown, and all of the conditions for being focused were met.

Comment: Are you talking about my code snippet? Or about your code? Then provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I used addEventListener, jQuery listeners, and the onkeydown listeners but only the first worked. I have no idea why that is, but in the end it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("a");
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <input  type="text"  name="container" id="container" value=""  onkeydown="myFunction()">
       </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```